# Point cloud texture alpha blending (THREEJS)

Tags: three.js, shader, textures, fragment-shader, blending

I use ShaderMaterial to create point cloud with attribute based size and opacity.
I also need to texture map. The problem is that texture is rendered without transparency.
Looks like each texture pixel color is blended somehow with background color (white in this case);
How to avoid this this?

[image]

I use svg texture:

```
<div id="circle-texture" style="width: 0; height: 0; display: none">
    <svg width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="13" stroke="none" fill="white" fill-opacity="1" />        
    </svg>    
</div>
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="point-cloud-fragment-shader">

...  

uniform sampler2D texture;   

varying vec3 vColor;

varying float vOpacity;   

#include <clipping_planes_pars_fragment>

void main() {

    #include <clipping_planes_fragment>

    vec3 outgoingLight = vec3( 0.0 );

    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4( diffuse, vOpacity );  

    if (enableTexture) {            
        vec4 mapTexel = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );            
        diffuseColor *= mapTexelToLinear( mapTexel );
    }

    diffuseColor.rgb *= vColor;

    outgoingLight = diffuseColor.rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( outgoingLight, diffuseColor.a );
}
```

Discarding fixes if:

```
if ( gl_FragColor.a < 0.001 ) discard;
```

**But is it possible without discarding? (with custom blending or something else)** I've played with custom blending but without success so far.

[image]

Comment: Discarding fragments in the shader is definitely a valid approach since it's the same what `three.js` does when configuring [Material.alphaTest](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.alphaTest). Can you please demonstrate your progress of work as a live example that shows your custom blending?

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks but why the discard condition works (alpha exists and it is small), but I don't see any transparency (alpha output) without discard?

Comment: Have you set the `transparent` property of your shader material to `true`?

Comment: @Mugen87 Yes, sure

Comment: @SalientBrain Try `material.depthWrite = false` and `points.renderOrder = 999;`

Comment: renderOrder is not suitable for ShaderMaterial. depthWrite = false works but it looks like performance-wise it is worse and being composed with other objects ('layers') it has 'always on top' rendering side effect. It is still strange that texture alpha is not used.

Answer (score 0):

The setup that works when dealing with partially-transparent point-clouds is to turn `transparent: true`, `depthTest: false` and a [blending mode](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/constants/Materials) if necessary. Additive or multiplicative blending look nice, depending on your use-case, and it removes the need to sort the depth of your sprites, since blending removes the need to place a color "in front" of the other:

```js
const spriteMat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        // List of uniforms
    },
    vertexShader: spriteVert,
    fragmentShader: spriteFrag,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    depthTest: false,
    transparent: true
});
```

Turning `transparent: true` respects the alpha channel in your fragment shader, so you'll no longer need to discard pixels.